# laravel didn't identify ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel-request

I tried sending login post method with ajax and in the controller method I have something like

```
if(Request::ajax()){
        return 'success';
}else{
        return 'false';
}
```

every time i send ajax request with my html page it returns **false** instead of **success**

Help me out.

Comment: Are you sure It's returning false?

Comment: yes i am. it happens when i try remote ajax request but when i am in same server it works fine

Comment: Would you mind sending your request? I mean the ajax one

Answer (score 1):

Replace use Illuminate\Http\Request with use Request.